# Getting all TFS 2012 Alerts

Tags: tfs, tfs-alerts, tfs-2012

I am a TFS Administrator and have created Team Alerts to send an alert when a work item is assigned to someone on the team. The alert I created is below:

```
Team Project = Team Name
AND Assigned To Changes To [ME]
AND Authorized As <> [ME]
```

The issue is that I get an alert when anyone on the team creates or changes a work item. In this example, I am not the assignee for any of these work items but still get alerts. I would expect only the person who is listed as the assignee should receive the alert. We are using TFS 2012. I am getting a lot of alerts each day (like 400) since we have many teams and need to get this issue resolved.

Any ideas on the issue?

Comment: If you click on My Alerts, does it show any additional alerts you are subscribed to, that could be sending the alerts?

Comment: On the Alert Administration page, I pulled up my name and I have 1 alert for each team. Each alert is the exact same as I mentioned above except for the Team Name which identifies the team. We are on TFS 2012 Update 3 ( I didn't see any fixes in the Update 4 regarding alerts so we haven't updated yet)

Comment: Additional information:

    I am a TFS Administrator
    I am a Project Administrator (for each tfs project)
    I am also listed as a Team member (for each tfs project)

It seems that all project administrators or TFS admins are getting all alerts (for any change or creation of a work item) So the issue isn't just with me.

Answer (score 0):

So does your alert look like this?

[image: Team Alert Screen for Work Item Assigned to Me]

Note the send to Text box

Comment: Thanks for your post! Yes, that is exactly how my alert is setup. Any ideas?

Comment: not sure then sorry, I have created the same on my server and will see what happens, and let you know. I was hoping that your send to may have been set up with individual email addresses, but at least now we have a view of your set up

Comment: Thank you! let me know how your test goes..Will you ensure you are listed as a member of your test team and also an project administrator for that project? I posted this issue on the msdn forums but didn't get much help there. Which version of TFS 2012 are you running? Update 3 or 4?

Comment: I have god rights to all collections and teams / projects on our server. Unfortuantely I'm running 2013 but at least i can confirm whether i see similar issues. I never saw this issue on 2012 in previous projects and that was from RC --> update4 as they were released.

Comment: Any update? I'm wondering if this may have anything to do with the fact that we are using a customized process template?

Comment: Working as expected here. Reading other questions on here seem to suggest you need to be AD for team alerts to work.

Comment: The team alerts are actually working for all team members except for TFS Admins and Project Administrators. TFS admins and the Project Admins are the ones who are seeing all alerts. Other team members such as contributors are getting the correct alerts.